# Error 1064 (42000): You have an error

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a table in my database but keep getting this error and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, here is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE Login_details (
username varchar(10) NOT NULL,
password varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
Employee_ID FOREIGN KEY (`Employee_ID`) REFERENCES `employee_details` 
(`Employee_ID`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Employee_ID isn't defined on your table.

Comment: Also I'm going to go ahead an assume you're going to store the passwords in plain text, you definitely shouldn't do that, they should be hashed. The way you do that will vary on your programming language.

Comment: Employee_ID is the primary key of another table, called employee_details. And thank you for letting me know about that, I'll probably change it once I've got all my tables.

Comment: That's not how foreign keys work. You need to have the same column on this table too.

Comment: @Augwa how would I do that using my code?

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you would do this. Change the datatype of `INT` on the `Employee_ID` column here to match the same datatype on the `employee_details` details table.

However since this is a 1-1 relationship, why not just add it to your existing table, doesn't seem to make sense to break this out.

```
CREATE TABLE `Login_details` (
  `Employee_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Employee_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Employee_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`Employee_ID`) REFERENCES `employee_details` (`Employee_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```